# ReactJS : How to render a value obtained from websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have the following code. In console I receive this correctly:

[image]

Every this is working and each time a new value is received from the WebSocket a new console message appears.

How to extract the value of `p` and render it just after `VALUE:`? Will this value change every time event is produced?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    dataFromServer: []
  };

  ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/xrpeur@trade");

  //Esperamos a que los daos sean cargados.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
      // on connecting, do nothing but log it to the console
      console.log("connected");
    };

    this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
      // listen to data sent from the websocket server
      const message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
      this.setState({ dataFromServer: message });
      console.log(message);
    };

    this.ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log("disconnected");
      // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        VALUE:{" "}
        {this.state.dataFromServer.map(valor => (
          <p>{valor.e}</p>
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: `message` appears to be an `object` rather than an `array`. So `VALUE: {this.state.dataFromServer.p}` should work. Also you might need to change `state = { dataFromServer: [] };` to `state = { dataFromServer: {} };`

Comment: Thks works! great,.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push multiple `message` to `dataFromServer` state, you should to use:

```
this.setState(prevState =>{dataFromServer: [prevState.dataFromServer, ...message]})
```

to prevent losing previous data. The other codes you used is correct

Answer (score 0):

The value from `JSON.parse(evt.data)` is an object. Remove your call to map and just access the properties on `this.state.dataFromServer` directly. Also, it looks like `e` is always `"trade"`, so you won't see that update.

Check out this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mountain-3cl8o?file=/src/App.js) to see it working.